# How do I scrape the data from this table using R?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, data-collection

I am trying to extract the data here: https://entp.hud.gov/idapp/html/condo1.cfm using the rvest package for R.

I suspect that I am at minimum missing some steps but unsure where to start.

The results from the r code below seem to be the fields from the prior page.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://entp.hud.gov/idapp/html/condo1.cfm"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table()
```

Comment: hi lhilsbos! Welcome to Stack Overflow! General rule: if table requires you clicking any buttons to load it, it's Javascript. Get javascript tables with RSelenium